# LibGDX + ARCore: Usage of multiple cameras and viewports

Tags: opengl, libgdx, google-project-tango, perspectivecamera, arcore

I have an app combining LibGDX and ARCore, based on https://github.com/google/helloargdx This works perfectly for the fullscreen.

Now I have a different requirement: I split the landscape oriented screen vertically and now want to render the world from the perspective camera controlled by the ARCore camera to the left side and a second time with a different perspective camera controlled externally to the right side.

For the "background" video (phyiscal device camera) this is already working, but I am at the moment stuck on the viewport (or whatever) from LibGDX's Perspective Camera.

The ARCore Example sets the perspective camera's values like this:

```
float vm[] = new float[16];

Camera arCamera = frame.getCamera();
arCamera.getProjectionMatrix(vm, 0, camera.near, camera.far);
camera.projection.set(vm);
arCamera.getViewMatrix(vm, 0);
camera.view.set(vm);
camera.combined.set(camera.projection);
Matrix4.mul(camera.combined.val, camera.view.val);
```

But how can I now (after the above) restrict the rendering to the left portion of the screen ? The "x-middle" of the old screen setting should now be the 1/4th of the physical screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It turned out, that it is not even necessary to work with Viewports etc, we can simply restrict the drawing area on the surface by using

```
HdpiUtils.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

However you need to be aware, that you now also need to convert screen taps by e.g.:

```
int x = Gdx.input.getX() * 2;
int y = Gdx.input.getY();
```

Because of shrinking the viewport to a portion of the original screen, but all input handling methods expect the screen taps to originate from a fullscreen.

Comment: Can you share how you fixed the bug in helloargdx - https://github.com/google/helloargdx/issues/3

Comment: I do not draw the planes, and this seems to be from where the bug originates. So if you don't want to display the panes (and in a productive environment you most like really don't want to), it should not affect you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and see how it goes